# How to create .exe from my c# form application project

Tags: c#, executable

I wish to ask you how to create a workable .exe from my form application project.

Project name is lottery and when I started the Build solution , program say me, that build is successed, after that I'm going to

> C:\Users\mdinev\Desktop\LottaryPresentation\Lottary.Business\bin\Debug

This is exactly my path, but here is also my .dll and config file.

I'm working with VS2015 and my target is to give this .exe to other department team to started a lottery program.

Is it possible to create this exe file, may be they have to insall other version ot .net framework, but other team only wish for me to present them an .exe file. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: change 'debug' to 'release' in dropdown next to 'start'

Comment: What type is your project? Look in the project properties and check the "Output Type". What is it?

Comment: Type is Class library

Comment: Just read **[this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z(v=vs.90).aspx)**... or any other...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Output type to **Windows Application** and you will get your .exe file.

Edit:
You can do that by right-click your project, go to Properties/Application and change the **Output type** from **Class Library** to **Windows Application**

Comment: Yes, I found it :)